# Navbar fade out issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, navbar

This is really a matter of me messing around in the CSS, and ending up unknowingly deleting or overriding something. When I hover over the nav link which drops down a list, it fades in. However, it doesn't fade out when it disappears after moving the mouse away.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/)

```
<nav class="bg">
    <ul class="width nav">
        <li><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">DropLink</a>
            <ul class="drop dr2">
                <li><a href="#" title="link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span></span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (sorry for the mess on this one. In the full CSS file, it's all combined to save on space):

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:small;font-family:Roboto;vertical-align:middle;}
.drop,nav{border:1px solid #BBB;}
body>.main,nav>ul{font-size:0;}
.width{margin:0 auto;width:84%;}
.width,.bg{min-width:1000px;}
.bg,.drop{background:linear-gradient(#444,#000,#444);}
nav{border-left:none;border-right:none;}
nav>ul:after{content:"";}
nav a{padding:8px;}
nav a:hover, nav a:active{color:#BBB;}
.drop{z-index:2;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;opacity:0;border-top:none;}
.dr1{transform:translateX(-28.5%);width:230%;}
.dr2{transform:translateX(-27%);width:216%;}
.drop li{white-space:nowrap;display:block;}
.nav li:hover .drop{left:0;top:100%;opacity:1;transition:opacity .5s,top 0s,left 0s;}
nav span{border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #555;padding:7px 0;}
nav{font-weight:bold;}
nav>ul{text-align:justify;}
nav>ul,nav>ul:after{width:100%;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
a{color:#FFF;}
.nav li:hover .drop{text-align:center;}
nav a,nav li,nav>ul:after{display:inline-block;}
nav li,nav>ul{position:relative;}
.drop{position:absolute;}
```

While I'm asking, I might as well kill two birds with one stone and ask something else. If you zoom in on the bar where the borders are, you'll see that they don't actually have the same height as the navbar itself. If I increase the padding in the relevant area in my CSS, it becomes one pixel too long. If I don't, it's one pixel too short. It is never 100% the height of the bar. I asked this question not too recently, but after changing the entire navbar code, I've been unable to replicate the solution.

Comment: So... what's the original question about the navbar fade issue?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen for us to help you through this issue.

Comment: @Cam - there is a fiddle link towards the top.

Comment: @sbeliv01 oh, that's embarrassing! Edited at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only setting the `left` and `top` rules on hover, but when you aren't hovering the dropdown completely leaves the view, so although the opacity if fading, you can't see it.

What you need to do is change two group selectors to have the same position whether hovering or not.

E.G.

```
.nav li:hover .drop {
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity .5s, top 0s, left 0s;
}
```

Should become two selectors:

```
.nav li .drop {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s, top 0s, left 0s;
}

.nav li:hover .drop {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

In addition, your `text-align` property should be set even when not hovering, otherwise the text will shift left.

E.G.

**Delete:**

```
.nav li:hover .drop {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Add:**

```
.nav li .drop {
    text-align:center;
}
```

If you make these corrections, you should get: [jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/28](http://jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/28)

Note:

I don't want to be nitpicky, but your code is styled terrible and makes fixing things difficult, always try to make code readable. I did not clean up a lot of code here, although it should be.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. As for the code, when you refer to the styling, are you talking about how everything is all over the place, or the actual properties themselves being unnecessary, incorrect, etc?

Comment: When I say styling I'm specifically referring to the how the code *looks*. Not spacing things right, not using enough line breaks, etc. In addition, you have a lot of unnecessary selectors that would be compacted. In addition, I am not a fan of using things other than IDs and Classes, because they look a little neater and generally reduce errors.

Comment: @Hiigaran, Oh, I also noticed that in my example, hovering the mouse a little below the bar where the dropdown is causes it to show up, if you don't like that, you will need to change the `top` value, but must animate it to look decent. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/24/ for an example.

Comment: Ahh, damn. That sort of kills it. I might have to keep looking for a solution then.

Comment: @Hiigaran, Good news! So we can fix this problem by setting `pointer-events` to none, and then reset them on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/28/. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Bloody beaut you are! Hell, I've never even heard of pointer-events up until now. Looks like I've got some reading up to do.

Comment: @Hiigaran, My only warning is that unfortunately IE didn't support `pointer-events` until IE 11. That said, you can find several workarounds online which I won't bother mentioning in this answer.

Comment: Ahh, I'm not particularly worried about it. If people don't update at least on a semi regular basis, then that's their fault. The site this is going towards is meant for young adults and teenagers, so they will likely have more up to date software than older people. Also, I needed to add pointer-events:auto; to the hover selector, otherwise the dropdown disappears when you move your mouse over to it.

Comment: @Hiigaran, Cool, and the `pointer-events: auto` was in my answer and example. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider re coding this, half of your CSS was unecessary and also had to be cleaned up. I also took out code that was not needed, I can show you how to do it better, for instance the spaces with span elements, not necessary. Also, good code structure is important, as it will help you find and locate problems. I cleaned this up as best as I could. Again, this gets your first question done.

Here is just a few CSS changes that I made. Check the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PLbd/21/)

```
.drop {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
 }

ul.nav li:hover .drop {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to clean up his code. That said, this answer doesn't handle the `text-align` issue (mentioned in my answer), and also changes the layout of the bar (perhaps for the better), but not as the OP requested it.

Comment: Unfortunatly it did not answer the question entirely as the problems with the persons issue is more extensive then previously conceived. What I did is create exactly what they wanted, and cleaned up much of the garbled CSS.

Comment: While it doesn't solve the issue, I'm still curious as to what can be cleaned up, or written differently. At the moment, things look all over the place, because there are other styles that I omitted. These other styles are combined so that file size is lowered. By doing this, I have saved about 25% on file size.

Comment: You are using LI's with span classes to create borders for one. Second it would be easier to know exactly how you want this to look. You have widths that are set to enormous widths. Again, this might work for you but its unnecessary imo. Again, cleaner is better, but again that is my own way of coding.